# CONECTAR PHP CON WORD

Tags: php, phpword

quisiera conectar php en una plantilla en word, he visto algunas opciones en laravel y php puro, me recomiendan infopatch, o realizarlo desde forms con ifttt, ustedes que me recomiendan. Lo que si es necesario que se pueda usar desde la web y descargarlo desde la web.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usar desde la web que cosa? descargar desde la web que cosa?

Answer (score 0):

Yo he  utilizado esta librería.
Esto te permitirá procesar plantillas de una manera muy facil, te sugiero que crees un archivo a partir de tu plantilla y cuando lo edites entonces le devuelves la url de descarga al cliente.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord